# Timeout for aggregated records in Kafka table?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka for processing messages. Messages can be divided on a few parts (it's a composite message). So in stream I can have for example one composite message that is divided on three parts. In other words it will be three records in Kafka stream, but it's one big message. I want use Kafka table for merge parts of composite message in one Kafka record. After merge one message will be inserted in database (Postgres). Every part has number and total number of parts. For example if I have three parts (three Kafka records) of one message in stream - every parts has field total number of parts with value 3.

How I understand, task is simple in positive scenario: aggregate parts in table, create stream from table and filter records that have equals aggregated parts size and total number of parts, map filtered in one merged message and insert it in database (Postgres).

But negative scenario is also possible. In rare cases one of parts can be not inserted in Kafka at all (or it will be inserted much later, after timeout). So for example in stream only two parts from three of one composite message will be present. And this case I must insert in database (Postgres) not fully constructed message (it will consist only two parts, not three). How can I implement this negative scenario in Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check out punctuations: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-a-stream-processor

Also note, that you can mix-and-match Processor API and DSL: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration

If you provide a store name for the KTable aggregation, you can connect the store to a custom processor that registers a punctuation. Overall, it might be better to use Processor API for the whole application instead of the DSL though.